# lookaround in POSIX regex to match all spaces except the last (for gsub)

Tags: regex, gsub, ingest

...freaking out because of this simple problem:

I'm using an *Ingest pipeline* with the gsub processor to **replace all (white)spaces except the last**.
E.g.:

`"hello world regex is fubar "` to result in `"hello, world, regex, is, fubar"`

How can I convert the **PCRE** syntax (which won't work gsub TRE patterns, as I found out)

```
"/\s(?=.\S*)/g"
```

To **POSIX**, like...

```
"/[[:space:]](?=.[[:space:]]*)/g"
```

(only spaces exchanged, not the lookaround)

Edit: As I can only provide the regex in a string, I cannot use another processor than gsub. '\s' or '\S' are apparently marked as "unknown".

Comment: POSIX regex (whether ERE or BRE which are the regex two flavours POSIX defines) do not implement lookarounds.

Comment: @Aaron Oh, thank you for pointing that out. DO you know how I can achieve an equivalent with a POSIX regex?

Comment: I think I'd use `sed -E 's/\s+(\S)/, \1/g'` or similar, i.e. matching an extra non-whitespace character that follows a sequence of space and refering it inside the replacement pattern

Comment: Using `awk` rather than `sed` it looks like this would be a solution : `awk '{ r=gensub(/\s+(\S)/, ", \\1", "g"); print r }'`; apparently one needs to use `gensub` rather than `gsub` in order to use backreferences in the replacement pattern.

Comment: gsub is the only processor provided in the pipeline for doing such things. After testing I realized literals like '\s', '\S' are not recognized. For whatever reason... I can only provide the regex in a String - I do not have access to code.

Comment: Easily do it with `[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]|$)` pattern and `, \1` or `, $1` replacement. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDB23c/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is this possible without using another regex for the replacement string, without capturing a group?

Comment: Replacement string is not a regex. It is a replacement pattern. You can't use lookaheads with a POSIX regex.

Comment: Oh, that's what I meant. I got it working using `+(.)"` while avoiding `[:space]` . Another solution is `+([^ ])`

Comment: `\s` and `\S` are Perl extensions just like lookarounds, though they were introduced already in Perl 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Worked** using `" +([^ ])"` - another solution would be `" +(.)"`.
(Both without the double quotes)

with the replacement/substitution string `,$1`.

Thanks to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) for pointing this out.

For whatever reason the POSIX literal `[:space]` does not work, why `[[:space:]]+(.)` did not work either, even tho it is a **correct regex**.